# Why is my while loop not executing when the syntax seems to be correct

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop

I have been trying to debug this loop for a while now (no pun intended!)

I wonder if anyone can tell me if I am missing something obvious

### code below

```
echo enter number of occupants
read occupant_number
echo $occupant_number
i=0

while [$i -lt $occupant_number]
do
    echo "Enter occupant${i+1}'s name"
  read occupant${i+1}_name 
  echo "Enter occupant${i+1}'s MAC address"
  read occupant${i+1}_macaddress
  i=i+1
done
```

**the console output is below:**

 bash main.sh
enter number of occupants
5
5
main.sh: line 7: [0: command not found

---

Line 7 is the line with the  `while [$i -lt $occupant_number]`

Any help with getting this working is greatly appreciated guys!
Thanks

Comment: The *syntax* is fine; you  are just trying to execute a command named `[0` instead of a command named `[` due to the missing whitespace. Run your code through shellcheck.net

Comment: Many thanks @chepner
that was the issue indeed!
shellcheck.net is super useful! cheers